# How to keep column headers when using grep?

Tags: terminal, console, grep, output, find-occurrences

The output of some programs start with column names (e.g., `ps a`):

```
$ ps a

  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1306 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
 1318 hvc0     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty hvc0 38400 vt100-nav
14696 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
15283 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps a
```

Now, let's say I want to find the occurances of *agetty*:

```
$ ps a | grep agetty

 1318 hvc0     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty hvc0 38400 vt100-nav
15339 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep agetty
```

Unless I've seen the beginning of `ps a`'s output, I don't know what the output of `ps a | grep agetty` means.

I could print the first line followed by the matched lines:

```
$ ps a | head -n1; ps a | grep agetty

  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1318 hvc0     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty hvc0 38400 vt100-nav
15542 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep agetty
```

However, this doesn't solve my problem when I don't know how many header lines there are. 
Is there a method to get the headers and the matched lines, or some short workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this help?

```
 ps ..|awk '/yourpattern/ ||!/^\s*[0-9]/'
```

fill `yourpattern` in place.

also you could do `ps ...|awk '/agett[y]/ ||....` instead of `/agetty/` to filter the `awk` process self out.